# sample code for java backend in google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When i read doc of backend its tells how to configure ,etc.What what the code of a backend looks like?Is it just a servlet with extra entries in backend.xml file?

I tried to create  a servlet with class com.xyz.Mybackend and servlet name Mybackend.

```
public Mybackend  extends HttpServlet{

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){

   while(true){
     //do something
     try{
      Thread.sleep(xyz);
     }catch(Exception ex){

     }
   }

}
```

Then i added following lines in  backend.xml

```
<backends>
    <backend name="Mybackend">
    <class>B1</class>
    <options>
    <dynamic>true</dynamic>
    </options>
    </backend>
</backends>
```

Is that correct/enough?If yes.How to i start my backend now?It it by calling the backend servlet url?

`http://localhost/mybackenurl`  ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, backends are just servlets.
2. You have to start backends manually via `appcfg` script: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#Backend_States

Comment: @So Can i trigger that backend using a http request.I had tried it but i got some exception.Is my implemtation of sample backend correct?

Comment: Backends can not be started programmatically. You need to start them manually via `appcfg`. Once started you can, of course, invoke servlets on them that you wrote.

Comment: What i want to do is just run a thread continuously.Can you give me some sample code?What can i do to get the back end start at some interval?Is my sample code correct?

Comment: Backend can be started programatically by, for example, cron requests

Comment: You can also start the backend by deploying it using the google plugin for eclipse

Answer (score -1):

I know what you mean. I would have found the whole backends overview section a lot clearer the first time I read it if right at the top it said, backends are just special instances of servlets.

A popular way of starting a backends noone here has mentioned is by using push queues, as documented here, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Java_Push_queues_and_backends